# Native JavaScript select onchange this.value undefined

Tags: javascript, html

I have a select tag that is generated by a php file that I would rather not have to change if it can be avoided.  I also do not have the ability to use jQuery to solve my problem.  So here is how I am trying to set an onchange event:

```
var d = document.getElementById('lang_choice');
d.onchange = function(){
    window.alert(this.value);
}
```

The pop up box just says undefined.  I have checked the html and it has the value attributes set in the option tags.  So I am guessing I misunderstand something about this system and some explanation would be great.

Comment: Works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/uEPbH/ . The fact that the `alert` is executing at all means that you've bound the event properly. So I have no idea what the problem could be unless you can reproduce it in a jsFiddle.

Comment: Which browser are you targeting? I have a feeling that this will work in modern browsers but fail in older ones (IE8, etc.)

Comment: Weird, I thought this was right... how should I debug?  Can I do something to determine what's going on inside the 'this' object?

Comment: @JustinNiessner You are right. I just tested my fiddle on IE7 and it alerts nothing

Comment: @JustinNiessner Actually, as long as you provide the `value` attribute for the `<option>` elements, it works fine in IE7: http://jsfiddle.net/uEPbH/1/

Comment: @Ian - How did you get the Fiddle to run in IE7? I can't get JSFiddle to render a page at all in anything lower than IE9.

Comment: @JustinNiessner You have to append "show/" to the URL. For example: http://jsfiddle.net/uEPbH/1/show/ - you don't get the editor, but you get the page.

Comment: @Ian - I would toss that into an answer. It would seem, at least to me, that the OP is using an older browser and isn't setting the `value` attribute of his `<option>`s.

Comment: @JustinNiessner What's weird though is that the OP says the `alert` says `undefined`, not an empty string. If it were empty, that would absolutely be the source

Answer (score 2):

```
var d = document.getElementById('lang_choice');
d.onchange = function(){
    window.alert(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);
}
```

It works in older browser.

Although your method should work. There must be error elsewhere in your code. Check console.

Comment: While this is an option, you should explain it, or at least explain why it would/could be better.

Comment: I see no reason to do so. Average developer will know what's going on. It's not Assembler.
Less text = more time for me and others.

Comment: Not everyone that comes to this site is an "average developer". Especially not one that fully understands the DOM or its quirks. At the same time, your suggestion is unnecessary, as using `.value` works just as fine.

Comment: Actually when I did this, the pop up window didn't even come up with the word undefined. this.options is undefined.

Comment: @4th_dimention Here this method works: http://jsfiddle.net/uEPbH/2/ There must be error elsewhere in your code. Did you check console?

Comment: Yeah I've figured it out now.  I accidentally had another element on the same page with the same id.  It was grabbing that one instead of the select.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you bind onchange event once DOM object available and make sure option tag value attribute.

```
<select id="lang_choice">
  <option value="en">English</option>
  <option value="es">Spanish</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is helped for me.

For select:

```
$('select_tags').on('change', function() {
    alert( $(this).find(":selected").val() );
});
```

For radio/checkbox:

```
$('radio_tags').on('change', function() {
    alert( $(this).find(":checked").val() );
});
```

Comment: The question specifically says that jQuery is not possible in their case.

Answer (score -1):

IE has a bug(Not sure about versions), onchange will be fired before even value is set, so use like below

```
var d = document.getElementById('lang_choice');
d.onchange = function(){
   var th = this;
   setTimeout(function(){ window.alert( th.value ); }, 10);
}
```